# Enable/disable an effect via a binding

Tags: xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, an effect can be added in XAML, like this:

```
<Label ... >
    <View.Effects>
        <effects:MyGlowEffect Radius="10" Color="White"/>
    </View.Effects>
</Label>
```

---

**GOAL:**

I want this effect to only be active when a boolean in my ViewModel is true.  E.g. the equivalent of (**fake code - no such property "IsEnabled"**):

```
<effects:MyGlowEffect Radius="10" Color="White" IsEnabled="{Binding EnableEffect}"/>
```

How can I accomplish this?

I thought of using a `Trigger`, but I don't understand how a trigger could attach/detact an Effect. Nor how to have the Effect written in XAML, if it is sometimes attached and sometimes not.

I'm not looking for an answer that involves a custom renderer, or re-writing the effect as something else (a behavior?) - unless that is an easy rewrite. Because the effect already has been written, and this dynamic attachment is only desired in one place.

---

**MY FALLBACK DESIGN:**

If there is no simple solution, I'll make two versions of the View that needs the effect: one with it and one without it. Have the binding control which of those is visible - I already have the InverseBooleanConverter that is involved in that solution. Which looks like this:

```
<Label ... IsVisible="{Binding EnableEffect}">
    <View.Effects>
        <effects:MyGlowEffect Radius="10" Color="White"/>
    </View.Effects>
</Label>

<Label ... IsVisible="{Binding EnableEffect, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Since this is my own custom effect, this should be solvable by adding a custom parameter, and binding that to the boolean in ViewModel as in [Docs: Passing Effect Parameters as Attached Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties). (AFAIK, must use "attached" property, in order to use a Binding - effect properties don't appear to respond to dynamic changes.)

However, if there is some "generic" way to do this, for example to enable/disable an effect that I don't have source to, I would prefer that as a solution.

Comment: I had done something similar with a boolean on my Effect, What is used to do was Bind that boolean to a Property in my C# code. Then Based on different conditions or Triggers I used to change that boolean that was in my effect, Which used to basically remove the effects of the Effects. I hope i am making sense!

Comment: @Toolmakersteve,How do you use ViewModel in your code? If can use binding directly, I think Nick's reply can solved your problem.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT - read my new comment on Nick's answer. **Suppose there is an effect that doesn't have any property on it to turn it on/off.** I was wondering if there is the equivalent of a view's "IsVisible=False", but for an effect. So that the effect's `OnAttached` would not get called, so the effect would do nothing. If there is no "general" way to "detach" **any** effect (w/o writing code to physically remove it from the view hierarchy), then I will accept Nick's answer - and use a property specific to the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your were totally right about triggers, you can modify the existing like in my sample, or just add a new one like i guess you wanted:

```
<Label ...>       
    <View.Effects>
        <effects:MyGlowEffect Radius="10" Color="White" />
    </View.Effects>    
    <Label.Triggers> 
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnableEffect TargetType="Label" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="effects:MyGlowEffect.Radius" Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="effects:MyGlowEffect.Color" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>  
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Comment: Can you think of any way to enable/disable an effect, if one does not have access to the source of the effect? (In my current situation, I do have source, but I'm wondering for future effects.)

Comment: i don't understand, in this example we do not need the effect source its viable for any effect

Comment: What you show is how to set an effect's property to a value. What I am asking is how to completely disable an effect, as if it was not there (not attached). If the effect has a property that can be used to "turn it off", then yes this technique can be used. (In the example I give, probably setting radius to 0 or color to transparent will work. So I will mark this as answer if it is the only known approach.) But suppose an effect isn't designed to be turned on/off? I was wondering if there is a general technique that can be used to disable any effect? Probably not, just thought I would ask..